# NameError: 'user' not defined: Trying to extend abstract user model - DJANGO

Tags: python, django, abstract

First attempt at trying to create a student user by extending the User model.

> Issue: Upon clicking register btn i.e.Login (btn) instead of
>   redirecting to home it shows the following: NameError at /register/ 
>   ...name 'user' is not defined
>
> File "E:\ifb299\tutorial2\accounts\views.py", line 33, in register
>       Students.objects.create(user=user) NameError: name 'user' is not defined [25/Mar/2018 14:38:07] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 67801

**Not really sure what I'm doing wrong, why is Students.objects.create(user=user) wrong and how do i fix it, please?**

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.shortcuts import redirect

from accounts.forms import RegistrationForm, EditProfileForm

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from accounts.models import Students

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html')

def login_redirect(request):
    return redirect('/login/')

def register(request):
    # Once register page loads, either it will send to the server POST data (if the form is submitted), else if it don't send post data create a user form to register
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            Students.objects.create(user=user)
            return redirect('../home/')
    else:
        #  Create the django default user form and send it as a dictionary in args to the reg_form.html page.
        form = RegistrationForm()
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)

@login_required 
def view_profile(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)

@login_required 
def edit_profile(request):
     # Handle post request - if the user submits a form change form details and pass the intance user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('../profile')
    # Handles the get request - if no post info is submitted then get the form and display it on the edit profile page. 
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/profile_edit.html', args)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from django.db.models.signals import *
from django.conf import settings

class Students(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Create a custom form that inherites form UserCreationForm (adding our own fields to save i db)
# Inheriting form in the paramters ()
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm): 
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Students
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'bio',
            'location',
            'birth_date',

        )   

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user

#  Inherits from UserChangeForm class - we keep everything i.e. methods, functionality same but change the things we want to show - connected to the User model 
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # Create fields variable get has all the fields we want to show 
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password'
        )
```

Comment: You cant just make up a variable called `user` and expect it to magically contain the data it needs! :'( You need to define `user` somewhere or just pull from request form data

Answer (score 0):

first, you did not save the return value of `form.save()` to the variable `user`.

second, there is no field `user` your model `Student`.